# Is it wrong to skip the pronoun when writing in the first person?

Tags: grammar, orthography, formality

When writing short texts, usually detailing something I have done, I tend to not use the "I" pronoun in front of verbs, usually in front of past-tense constructions. Have seen it in emails from an indian professor and thought of it as an advanced speaker practice. However, I don't think I've seen this done elsewhere and have never before questioned it's correctness. Is is wrong?

Usage example:

> Have looked through all the available files these past hours, but haven't found anything of particular use.

Comment: Needs more information.  "Wrong" in what sense?  Of course it does not follow English grammar, but it may be acceptable anyway.

Comment: Welcome! 1) If you're learning English, questions about how speakers use the language idiomatically are often a better fit at the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange. 2) Agreed, for this to be answerable, please edit to tell more about what level of formality you're looking for. There's nothing *morally* wrong about answering "What you got?" with "I ain't got nothing." In fact, it's the "right" wording if it's what my hearer and context expect and it communicates my meaning well. Text messages and emails can be an appropriate place for non-standard usages

Comment: In email, *Looked through all files all day, but no luck* is plennee. Who'd say *I thank you for your time* in casual conversation?